# Making an async function out of delegate callbacks

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I want to implement an async/await interface on top of Core Bluetooth. I want to be able to say

```swift
let response = await sendBluetoothCommand(.myCommand)
```

Now, to send to via BLE, I write

```swift
peripheral.writeValue(bleCommand.payload, for: writeCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
```

and then I get the response in the delegate function

```swift
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) { ... }
```

Lets assume that the answer I want is the NSData from characteristic, so what I probably want across here is a Task.Handle<Data, Never>?

How can I make this task in the one function and complete it in the delegate function, so that it can act like in the first example?

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0300-continuation.md

Comment: Ah, so something like ```await withCheckedContinuation { (cont: CheckedContinuation<BLEResponse, Never>) in   
  peripheral.writeValue(bleCommand.payload, for: writeCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)   
// save 'cont' and 'later cont.resume(returning: response)'   
}```